# mysqldump causes 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: mysql

I setup a script to automatically backup the database and upload it to my Dropbox account, here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
mysqldump -u USER -PASSWORD DB_NAME | gzip -9 > /tmp/$DATE.sql.gz
./root/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /tmp/$DATE.sql.gz /
rm /tmp/$DATE.sql.gz
```

Credits to [andreafabrizi](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) and [INKHORN](http://www.inkhorn.ca/mysql-database-backups-using-dropbox-2/).

I put the file inside `/etc/cron.hourly`

It works just file, the only problem is that it causes `MySQL` to not answer any calls from `NGINX` during that time (while it creates the backup, depends on size, 20 MB takes about 20 seconds, I see this as serious problem when the database gets larger), which gives the `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: How long does the 502 last, on average? You could run this at the early hours of the morning (or whenever) when traffic is at its lowest.

Comment: @hd. Just edited my post: depends on size, 20 MB takes about 20 seconds, I see this as serious problem when the database gets larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142501/3953404

Just added this to the command:

```
--single-transaction --quick
```

In context with my code:

```
mysqldump -u USER -PASSWORD --single-transaction --quick DB_NAME
```

Problem solved :)