# Is it safe taking an SQL export form a running production GCP SQL service?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We have one Google Cloud SQL instance with 1 vCPU for production. I want to grab a copy of the data by exporting to a bucket. Is this safe to do? As in might it block other operations on the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important to take into consideration the RDBMS that you are using, it's mentioned in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/known-issues#import-export) that PostgreSQL has issues when handling big blobs in an export, and at this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666784/how-can-i-slow-down-a-mysql-dump-as-to-not-affect-current-load-on-the-server) there's an answer with the most votes with hints to have an smoother export, since it can lead to DBs getting unresponsive, which is a pretty well known fact.

In the case of MySQL, the product doc have some tips for this case in this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) where it stated:
"If the server is running, it is necessary to perform appropriate locking so that the server does not change database contents during the backup"

And you can achive this by using mysqldump --lock-tables=false into your export command.